# Hi, I have data where i want to convert values into Numeric values and want to plot a point graph

Tags: r

Below Data is my working data
**

Brand     CompanyAdvertising**

Apple     $719M

Google    $3.6B

Microsoft $3.2B

CocaCola  $4B

Facebook  $281M

Disney    $120M

I want to convert the above data into below data ( in company advertising column want to change all values into Numeric and in same unit i.e in Billions)

**Brand  CompanyAdvertising**

Apple     .719

Google    3.6

Microsoft 3.2

CocaCola  4

Facebook  .281

Disney    .120

I request to please help me. I am currently doing it like this way i am as.numeric(gsub('[$,M]', "", data$CompanyAdevertising))*1e-3.....Now that ouput which i am getting is

**.719 NA NA NA .281 .120

Warning message:

NAs introduced by coercion**

Comment: want to do it in R. also not a proper view is coming.  both are data frames with columns Brand and Company advertising

Comment: bdw the values in the output mentioned are wrong

Comment: You would be more likely to get help if you tried something out (with code) and posted that.

Comment: @ Joel : Thanks i guess now it is corrected. can you please help me with this

Comment: @Mike : Thanks for your suggestion. I am trying like this as.numeric(gsub('[$,M]', "", data$coloumn)) , but it is not working. Really appreciate if you can help me with this.

Comment: No, I mean a complete, but small example. Otherwise know as a MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Should be like 10 lines. That is the best way to get people to help you - and it is also the best way to learn.

Comment: @ Mike : Thanks, will try to mention what i am doing and what error i am getting, may be them i can get help